# prevent mobile from going into sleep mode when app is running

Tags: android, sleep-mode

I want to prevent Android Mobile from going into sleep mode when my threads are sending HTTP request. as what happened while threads are doing HTTP calls mobiles goes to sleep mode and when user wakes up the phone threads never complete.

User has to restart the app. what to do? please help

Comment: they won't work http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/power_management.html#androidPowerWakeLocks

Comment: thousands of apps use Wake locks so if yours does not it implies that either your phone or your app is not functioning correctly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html). There are different kinds of wake locks so be sure to select the least aggressive one that meets your needs. In particular it sounds like you need a [Partial Wake Lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK).

> Partial Wake Lock - Wake lock that ensures that the CPU is running. The screen might not be on.

Also, make sure you add the permission `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` to your manifest. And finally be double sure to [Release](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html#release%28%29) your lock when you are done.

Comment: Badumtish. He probably didn't include the permission or something.

Comment: @Andrew: so whats the way out?

Comment: @Badumtish: it will throw Exception if you don't include proper permissions.

Comment: @Aizaz: maybe you should file a bug? Generally, if you want to keep the screen on while the UI is displaying, you use FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON for Activity window and hold a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK to keep the device 
running while you are not in its UI.

Answer (score 4):

To prevent the phone from sleeping you can use a [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) but you should be careful when doing this to not kill the user's battery. If the phone goes to sleep does the user really care if your app finishes the requests it was making?

You will also need the [WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WAKE_LOCK) permission.

Answer (score 2):

**for JAVA:** `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);` 
**for KOTLIN:**  `window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)`
Use this code, it will keep your device wake up and you didn't need any permission.